# Jest is unable to import default export from index file of absolute path: "ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I set up absolute path in my node.js typescript project.

Here's the content of my Jest config file (jest.config.js):

```js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  modulePaths: ['./src'],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper({
    '@/*': ['*'],
  }),
  clearMocks: true,
};
```

The above config enables Jest to understand absolute path in my code.

Below is a sample of my project structure. I have a `events` directory that has an `index.ts` file like so:

```
src       
└─ events       
   └─ index.ts
```

When I import the default export like so:

```js
import events from '@/events'
```

and run Jest it throws: "**ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'events'**"

but it works if I import the default export like so

```js
import events from '@/events/index'
```

How do I get Jest to recognize the `index.ts` file in the absolute path without explicitly specifying it?

Jest should be able to detect and use the index file of the absolute path when I import like so:

```js
import events from '@/events'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
}
```